# restore overridden window.JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, cross-browser

Some code that I don't have control over is overriding the global JSON object without checking if it's already implemented:

```
var JSON = {
  org: "http://www.JSON.org",
  copyright: "(c)2005 JSON.org",
  license: "http://www.crockford.com/JSON/license.html",
  stringify: function(a, g) {
     ...
```

The problem is that this version of the JSON parser is very old and has a bug, which is fouling up my attempts at serialization.  (Others have had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7571913/89218) with this implementation.)

Can I get at the browser's native implementation?  I thought [delete would work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319174/bringing-back-an-overridden-window-method), but it doesn't.  I suspect that's because JSON is an *object* and not a [method in the prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319688/89218).  Is there some other way to get at it?

Comment: Similar questions have popped up recently. You can create an empty iframe and get the JSON object from it. Or included a better library afterwards.

Comment: ohh, an empty iframe. That's very clever.  Surely that's the answer?

Comment: I'm curious how you can get the information from the DOM of the iframe, I thought that the browser sandboxed the javascript of the child frames ...

Comment: Well, this will of course only work in browsers which provide the JSON object. If you also have to supported older browsers, you definitely have to include another library.

Comment: @jcolebrand: Only if it is from a different domain. Empty iframes are from the same domain, so it can access the content. I will try to find the question.

Comment: Please do, that confuses me greatly

Comment: Yeah, creating a frame is the only way to do it. I feel kinda bad posting it as an answer given the comments, though I did start writing that before @FelixKling's comment. :)

Comment: So why wouldn't it make more sense if you can do it my way, and grab it BEFORE the other scripts run, and keep a pristine copy?

Comment: @jcolebrand: If he can inject code before the other, then yes, it makes more sense. But this is not clear from the question.

Comment: @jcolebrand In my particular case I can't run the code before the JSON object gets ruined.  I was also asking specifically for how to get the original native JSON object.  Anyway, your workaround is still a valid way to go about it.

Comment: I realize you were asking for the original, which I didn't know the contextWindow option, so TIL, but you also didn't tell us when you could grab it from the page load lifecycle. Cheers.

Comment: Updated my answer to be more complete, complimentary to the other answer, and for mild cleaning. Thanks all!

Comment: The *current* version of [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) by Crockford will only shim JSON if the functions are *not present*. Consider upgrading.

Comment: @pst noted below my answer where discussion of Crockford came up... so why did you mention it here?

Comment: **You are using an old outdated version. Consider updating it.** (It was a comment. And not exclusively for *you*, but for future readers as well.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create an `iframe` element (which will load `about:blank` and hence create a new context) and get a JSON object from there.

```
function restoreJSON() {
  var f = document.createElement("iframe");
  f.style.display = "none";
  document.documentElement.appendChild(f);
  window.JSON = f.contentWindow.JSON;
  document.documentElement.removeChild(f);
}
```

`about:blank` is loaded synchronously, so no need to wait for the `load` event. While this isn't restoring the original JSON object, it is getting one black-box identical to it.

Comment: `f` needs to be inserted to the DOM in order to have a `contentWindow`, but having `display:none` is possible.

Comment: @kay Per spec it shouldn't, and I believe at least the latest release of all browsers follow that.

Comment: Oh, the spec does require it.

Comment: On IE, trying to use the restored JSON gives ""Can't execute code from a freed script".  I think this is because the invisible iframe has been unloaded.  However, if we 'leak' the iframe, it works.

Comment: @paleozogt What IE version gives that?

Comment: @gsnedders IE9 on Win7.  An SO question about it is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script).

Answer (score 1):

Since the code that you don't have control over is overriding the original before you come along in the page, you have two options:

Inject an iframe and grab the JSON off the contextWindow (as indicated in the other answer on this question at the time of this edit), or, alternately, just use the https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js JSON library as your own insert. Note that using Crockford's does give cross-browser-guarantees of conformance, but the native implementations are often faster.

An alternative if you have the ability in the future to come along on the page before the offending code, is to inject something *before* that offending "code that helps" to grab the JSON object:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.myJson = window.JSON;
    </script>
 ....
```

Comment: Note that adding Crockford's script to this will cause missing features to be applied automagically to the overridden JSON object, and a small editing of his file will give you a brand new object.