# JavaScript Native Map class overriden by other library

Tags: javascript, global-variables, conflicting-libraries

I'm developing a JavaScript library and new Map() call causes the following JavaScript error on some websites using my library.

```
Map is not a constructor
```

When I execute console.log(Map) on Chrome developer console, I get the following result.

```
MapClass {mapmain: GoomapMapMainControl, methods: Array(0), callbackParams: Array(0), Slider: null, UIMapTool: UIMapToolClass, …}
```

It looks like old version of GoogleMap library overrides JavaScript's native Map class, and new Map() call inside my library is calling Google Map's Map class.

I can't update the GoogleMap library of all my users to fix the issue, so I need to modify my library to solve this issue.

Is it possible to call JavaScript Native Map class even when overridden? Or do I need to redefine Map class by copying native Map's source code? (Is it available somewhere?)

Comment: how old is the library!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129521/restore-overridden-window-json-object ?

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue. Is there any easy way to check if native Map class is overridden or not? I wrote "if (!Map.prototype || !Map.prototype.constructor || !Map.prototype.entries)" for now, but trying to find a better way.