# document.querySelectorAll("body") returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I am using the following codes in the console of the firefox DevTools to extract book names from https://bookauthority.org/books/best-problem-solving-books

**Code 1**

```
var selects=document.querySelectorAll("div.book-header-title a.book-title h2.main");

for (i = 0; i < selects.length; ++i) {
  console.log (selects[i].innerText);
}
```

**Code 2**

```
var selects=document.querySelectorAll("div.book-header-title a.book-title h2.main");
console.log(selects)
```

Even the following code is not working

```
var selects=document.querySelectorAll("body");
console.log(selects)
```

It only says `undefined`. What can I do?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` will never return`undefined`.

Comment: if you are running these in the dev tools, `undefined` will be the return value of console.log. Are you sure you're not seeing a NodeList above that?

Comment: Yeah, querySelectorAll will either return an object or null. The `undefined` is not the printout from console.log, it's the return value (void, esentially).

Comment: @DanOswalt yes I am sure, I have tried the codes I have given here on multiple websites. Everywhere it works except https://bookauthority.org/. I think they have done something to disable querying dom elements.

Comment: @DanOswalt: In the case of `querySelectorAll`, it'll actually always return an object. It'll just not have any members if none were found.

Comment: @slappy I have given the code, given the link. Please try it out.

Comment: I tried `document.querySelectorAll("body")` in the console on that page, and it returns a NodeLIst with the `body` inside.

Comment: @slappy good point, I was making assumption that it acted the same as getElementById, etc

Comment: @DanOswalt: The "single element" version `querySelector` behaves like that.

Comment: `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('body')[0]))` or `console.log(document.querySelector('body'))` or I use `document.body`, since `body` already a property of `document`. In old Browsers the `body` was undefined until the page already loaded. This behavior has been mostly changed, but I still recommend external JavaScript. Short incomplete example: `let doc, htm, bod; /* vars for use on other loads */ addEventListener('load', ()=>{ doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; /* now doc is document htm is the <html> Element bod is the <body> Element */ });`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` works just fine. The problem resides in that the specific webpage on which you're executing the code, has overriden the `window.console.log` method and the new implementation apparently does not print arguments to the console, as its native implementation does.

You can see this by issuing `window.console.log` (without parentheses), which usualy prints something like `ƒ log() { [native code] }` (at least in Chrome).

There are hacks how to acquire the native implementation. See, for example, this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11129588/4005175

---

Example:

```
// restore window.console.log method
var f = document.createElement("iframe");
f.style.display = "none";
document.documentElement.appendChild(f);
window.console.log = f.contentWindow.console.log;

// print book titles
var selects=document.querySelectorAll("div.book-header-title a.book-title h2.main");
for (i = 0; i < selects.length; ++i) {
  console.log (selects[i].innerText);
}
```

Comment: So, how can I get the book list?

Comment: I've added an example.